# Help correct - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FULL'

Tags: compile-error

```
SELECT 
    s.SubscriberKey, ss.EmailAddress, MIN(s.EventDate) as 'FirstClickDate', 
    o.Client ID, o.Account Email, o.Client Name, o.FULL CUSTOMER ID
FROM _Click s
JOIN _job j ON j.JobID = s.JobID AND j.accountid = 1384795
JOIN ENT._subscribers ss ON s.SubscriberID = ss.SubscriberID
JOIN [DS_Opportunity_Report] o ON s.SubscriberKey = o.FULL CUSTOMER ID
WHERE (j.EmailName = 'DealShieldOffer' and s.EventDate >= '5/9/2017')
GROUP BY 
    s.SubscriberKey, ss.EmailAddress, o.Client ID, o.Account Email, o.Client Name, 
    o.FULL CUSTOMER ID
```

Comment: How does this relate to Salesforce? Voting to close.

Comment: @BrianMansfield OP hasn't provided nearly enough context, but I think this is related to marketing cloud (which I do believe uses more traditional SQL)

Comment: After writing my answer, I've decided to downvote this question because it shows absolutely no research effort, and the tags (well...tag, as there's just one at time of writing) and content aren't sufficient to determine if this question is related to Salesforce or not.

Comment: Also, your question is severely lacking in detail. Things I would have liked to see in this question that would make it better are: 1) A description of what you're trying to do, or at least where you're trying to do it 2) More tags (is this related to marketing cloud, apex, visualforce, validation rules, etc...?) 3) A description of what you've tried to do to resolve the issue so far 4) Some words that show us what research you have done up to this point.

Comment: Also also, properly formatting your question does help. Long blocks of text make it harder for people to 'digest' (i.e. understand) your code, query, or general situation. There is a page on [editing help](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/editing-help) contains information on how to apply different formatting (e.g. making a list, quoting a source, making something appear as a block of code). This time, I've formatted your question for you by turning your query into a code block, and breaking long lines into multiple, shorter lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you certain that your column names are supposed to have spaces in them?

Some brief searching shows that this is possible with sql server and mysql (using backticks or enclosing in square braces), but it's not something I've run into before now (all database column names I've encountered are either `camelCase` or `underscore_spaced`).

A little more searching reveals that `FULL` is a reserved keyword in most RDBM systems.

Avoiding spaces in column names is generally good practice, but if you can't change that, using either backticks or square braces around `FULL CUSTOMER ID` (like perhaps `[o.FULL CUSTOMER ID]`) should fix things.

Comment: Thank you Derek, the brackets worked! Yes this a query in marketing cloud. sorry for jumbled question was trying to maneuver from my phone